# Running Parallel Databricks Notebooks using Python

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

I was trying to run 2 parallel notebooks in Databricks using python ThreadPoolExecutor.
I have referred [this](https://cloudarchitected.com/2019/05/running-azure-databricks-notebooks-in-parallel/) link. But I have 2 problems now

1. Exception is not thrown when the notebook is failed, because of which the retry is not working
2. How to fetch the latest result of notebook execution, this is required to make the parent notebook failed/Passed depending on the status of either of the child notebooks

Comment: are you using `dbutils.notebook.run` ? Please paste a code example

Comment: @dileep help us with the sample code